# Using lstm to find if and which timestep values are raised (with tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I want to classify parts of the sequence. So class 1 may be from time step 14 to 16 and possibly there is also a class 2 in the sequence from 10 to 14. The lengths of these parts can change. I thought the best way to do this is to take the output of timestep of the network and use a fully connected layer. In my setup this results in 6 classifications.

1. whether there is a class 1 [batch_size,2]
2. whether there is a class 2 [batch_size,2]
3. start timestep of class 1 [batch_size,time_steps]
4. end timestep of class 1 [batch_size,time_steps]
5. start timestep of class 2 [batch_size,time_steps]
6. end timestep of class 2 [batch_size,time_steps]

My problem is 2 fold:

- the first 2 classifications do not get better as a guess
- the last 4 classifications the bias to the 0 class becomes to high

Here is the code where I make the data:

```
def make_data(y = None,batch_size = 1, max_length = 100):
    f_name_values = []
    l_name_values = []
    X = np.random.randn(max_length,batch_size,1)
    if y is None:
        y_ = np.random.randint(0,2,(batch_size,2))
    else:
        y_ = y
    y_1 = np.zeros((batch_size,4),dtype =int)    
    y = np.concatenate([y_,y_1],axis = 1)
    seq_len = np.random.randint(int(max_length*0.2),int(max_length*0.6),(batch_size,1))

    for i in range(batch_size):
        f_name = np.random.randint(0,seq_len[i,0]-3)
        if y[i,0] == 1:
            y[i,2], y[i,3] = int(f_name), int(f_name + np.random.randint(1,3))
            X[y[i,2]:y[i,3],i,:] += 10

        l_name_list = [j for j in range(seq_len[i,0]) if not( j <= y[i,3] and j > y[i,2]) ]
        l_name = np.random.choice(l_name_list)        

        if y[i,1] == 1:            
            y[i,4], y[i,5] = int(l_name), int(l_name + np.random.randint(1,4))
            X[y[i,4]:y[i,5],i,:] += 10.5

    return X, y , seq_len
```

And part of my network:

```
   # Build RNN cell

    multi_encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units) for _ in range(layers)])
    # init_state = multi_encoder_cell.zero_state(tf_batch_size, tf.float32)
    # Run Dynamic RNN
    #   encoder_outputs: [max_time, batch_size, num_units]
    #   encoder_state: [batch_size, num_units]
    #   input: [max_time, batch_size, depth] w/ time_major= True
    encoder_outputs, encoder_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        cell = multi_encoder_cell, inputs = X,
        sequence_length=s_sequence_length[:,0], time_major=True,dtype = 'float32')

def rnn_out_2_logit(scope_name, encoder_outputs_, y, num_of_classes,w,b,is_from_certain_class = None):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope_name + '_2_logit'):
        output_ = encoder_outputs_[-1,:,:]
        logit = tf.matmul(output_,w) + b
        if num_of_classes > 10:
        # if the class (either 1 or 2) is not in the time serie their is no cost for the wrong class with the last 4 classifications
            bool_if_greater = tf.greater(is_from_certain_class,tf.zeros_like(is_from_certain_class)) 
            int_bool = tf.cast(bool_if_greater,tf.float32)
            cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = logit)
            cross_entropy = cross_entropy * int_bool
            t_cross_entropy = tf.where(tf.less(tf.reduce_sum(int_bool), 1e-7),1e-7,(tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)/tf.reduce_sum(int_bool) )* batch_size)            
            t_cross_entropy = tf.Print(t_cross_entropy, [t_cross_entropy, cross_entropy, int_bool],"cross_entrpy: ")
        else:
            t_cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = logit))
```

and here I call the function:

```
#class_1
cross_entropy_1, logit_l, l, acc_l = rnn_out_2_logit("class_1",encoder_outputs,y[:,0], num_class_f_l, w_l, b_l)
#class_2
cross_entropy_2, logit_f, f, acc_f = rnn_out_2_logit("class_2",encoder_outputs,y[:,1], num_class_f_l, w_f, b_f)
#class_1_start
cross_entropy_3, logit_f_num_start, _f_num_start, acc_f_s = rnn_out_2_logit("class_1_start",
                                                                            encoder_outputs,
                                                                            y[:,2],
                                                                            max_words+1,
                                                                            w_l_e, b_l_e, y[:,1])
#class_1_end
cross_entropy_4, logit_f_num_end, _f_num_end, acc_f_e = rnn_out_2_logit("class_1_end",
                                                                        encoder_outputs,y[:,3],
                                                                        max_words+1,
                                                                        w_f_e, b_f_e, y[:,1])
#class_2_start
cross_entropy_5, logit_l_num_start, _l_num_start, acc_l_s = rnn_out_2_logit("class_2_start",
                                                                            encoder_outputs,y[:,4],
                                                                            max_words+1,
                                                                            w_l_s, b_l_s, y[:,0])
#class_2_end
cross_entropy_6, logit_l_num_end, _l_num_end, acc_l_e = rnn_out_2_logit("class_2_end",
                                                                        encoder_outputs,y[:,5],
                                                                        max_words+1,
                                                                        w_l_e, b_l_e, y[:,0])
```

I think the if else structure is working oke because i print the result with tf.Print and there an example of the output (with batch_size = 3) is :

> cross_entropy: [4.7751608][0 5.9443221 3.605999][0 1 1]

I see that it is not getting better by the graphs i make on tensorboard and this print:

epoch = 0

> predicted y [[ 2.16714668 -1.0374999 ]] [[-0.30407697  0.01561086]] 99
>   3 35 99
>
> true y [[ 1  1 21 22 13 15]]

epoch =  100

> predicted y [[ 1.26584482 -0.13619883]] [[-0.17700087 -0.11146521]] 99
>   3 35 99
>
> true y [[ 1  1  5  6 32 33]]

epoch = 200

> predicted y [[ 0.70634729  0.42329881]] [[-0.1597006  -0.12876543]] 0
>   0 0 0 
>   true y [[ 1  1 22 24 38 40]]

I'm aware that I could do it in other ways(conv-net or seq2seq) however in order to be generalized for the use I want to put it this lay-out is preferred.

Any help is much appreciated. And thanks to anyone who made through this whole question.

**update 1**

I first should have spliced the task. So first problem 1 and then 2. Also I'm gonna try a regression with the second. To be continued.

**update 2**

In the end, I made a bidirectional rnn with ouputs at each timestep. Seems to work oke.

Comment: Have you tried outputting a class at *each* timestep? The begin/end approach seems hard to learn from. My first intuition would be to output class [0, 1, 2] where 0 is neither, and 1, or 2 is your first or second class. So your output layer is always [batch x 3].

Comment: thanks yeah I tried it but I couldn't make it work also I want to make use for NLP and than I need to make a bidirectional which complicates matter futher